# String replace exact match in cyrillic

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex for string replace with Cyrillic characters. I want to use exact match option. My string replace is working with Latin characters and is looking like that:

```
'Edin'.replace(/\Edin\b/gi, '');  // Output is ""
```

The same expression is not working with Cyrillic characters

```
'Един'.replace(/\Един\b/gi, '');  // Output is still 'Един'
```

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/42

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is `\b` word boundary chracter, which matches position at a word boundary. Word boundary is defined as `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. And in its turn [word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` is a set of ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_]. Obviously Cyrillic characters don't fall into this set.

For example, for the same reason `/\w+/` regular expression will not match Cyrillyc string.

Comment: That's good. It explains why it's not working but is there a solution.

Answer (score 4):

As **dfsq** wrote  the problem is with word boundary.
If you remove `\b` you will get desired output, but it is quite different regex. It will replace **Един** also in cases where it is a part of word. To avoid that you can use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and define which letters shouldn't appear behind, because they could be a part of word.

```
'Един'.replace(/\Един(?![A-я])/gi, '');
```

Comment: @user732456 Also can try `(?![\wЁ-ЌЎ-џ])` as boundary [(regex101)](http://regex101.com/r/qB8wM0/1)